# How to animate height auto in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have made vertical-drop-down menu.
The problem is when I want to add more submenu, I have to change the height each time.
Is there any way to make height auto ?

Fiddle here [[http://fiddle.jshell.net/E2EQn/]](http://fiddle.jshell.net/E2EQn/%5d)

This is my jquery code here

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#gnb").mouseover(function() {
        $('#header').animate({height: "349px"}, 200 );  // this height need to auto-height   
        $('#subLayer').css({height: "349px"});     // this height need to auto-height
        $('#subLayer ul').css({height: "349px"});  // this height need to auto-height   

    });
    $("#header").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).animate({height: "96px"}, 200 ); 
    });   
    $("#subLayer").mouseleave(function() {
        $('#header').animate({height: "96px"}, 200 ); 
    }); 

});
```

Comment: you can use ``min-height``

Comment: and also if you provide fiddle it will be more good

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad / please check my fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/E2EQn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're fine using jQuery UI, you can start using classes rather than explicit styles and then use the altered [`addClass`](http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/) and [`removeClass`](http://api.jqueryui.com/removeClass/) methods.

For example, if we had the HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

We could use this CSS:

```
div, h1, p {
    /* normalize */
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1;
}
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#container.collapsed {
    height: 1em;  /* just enough to show the header, but no content */
}
```

Then, we could make it expand or collapse on hover with jQuery rather easily: <kbd>[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xC5JD/)</kbd>

```
var container = $('#container').addClass('collapsed').hover(function() {
    container.removeClass('collapsed', 200);
}, function() {
    container.addClass('collapsed', 200);
});
```